# Password protected PDF to Image using iText5

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext

I want to get all PDF pages in Image format, it is possible with `PdfRenderer` but I can't input a PDF password with it.

Can I get images of a PDF page from PDFReader?

**here is my code**

```
 private void pdfToImage(Uri pdfFilePath, String password) { //password is input,which is given by user

        try {
            // Reading pdf in READ Only mode.
//        ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(new File(pdfFilePath.getPath()), ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
            ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(pdfFilePath, "r");
            
            // Initializing PDFRenderer object.
            PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(fileDescriptor);

            // Getting total pages count.
            final int pageCount = renderer.getPageCount();

            // Iterating pages
            for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {

                // Getting Page object by opening page.
                PdfRenderer.Page page = renderer.openPage(i);

                // Creating empty bitmap. Bitmap.Config can be changed.
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(page.getWidth(), page.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                // Creating Canvas from bitmap.
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

                // Set White background color.
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

                // Draw bitmap.
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);

                // Rednder bitmap and can change mode too.
                page.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);

                // closing page
                page.close();


                // saving image into sdcard.
                File file = getImageFile();

                // Saving image in PNG format with 100% quality.
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                Log.v("Saved Image - ", file.getAbsolutePath());
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: iText 5 does not support rendering PDFs to bitmap images. For iText 7 there would be the pdfRender add-on. I don't know, though, whether that is Android compatible.

Comment: @mkl iText 5 supports rendering PDFs to bitmap images, but we can't use `PdfRenderer` with encrypted PDF files, I just want Page images from it, That's it.

Answer (score 0):

After spending 2 days finally i found a solution to convert password protected pdf pages into bitmaps, i know it's too late but it can help someone, here i'm sharing some line of codes

by using this [library](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer)

1. First of all add below gradle dependency in build.gradle

   implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
2. Then you can use following function, it will return list of bitmaps

   ```
    fun mGetBitmapFromPasswordProtected(file: Uri?,password : String): ArrayList<Bitmap>? {

    val bitmaps = ArrayList<Bitmap>()

    var pageNum=0

    val pdfiumCore = PdfiumCore(this@PDFToImages)
    try {
        val pdfDocument = pdfiumCore.newDocument(
            contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(
                file!!, "r"
            ), password
        )


        do {
            pdfiumCore.openPage(pdfDocument, pageNum)
            val width = pdfiumCore.getPageWidthPoint(pdfDocument, pageNum)
            val height = pdfiumCore.getPageHeightPoint(pdfDocument, pageNum)
            val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                width, height,
                Bitmap.Config.RGB_565
            )
            pdfiumCore.renderPageBitmap(
                pdfDocument, bitmap, pageNum, 0, 0,
                width, height
            )

            bitmaps.add(bitmap)
            pageNum++
        }
        while (pdfDocument.hasPage(pageNum))


        pdfiumCore.closeDocument(pdfDocument)

        return bitmaps
    }
    catch (ex: Exception) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
   ```

   }